# How do you see the progress of your challenges in-game?

Tags: battlefield-1

In Battlefield 1, you can complete challenges to earn medals. However, oftentimes it is incredibly frustrating not knowing how far you are in these challenges. For instance, there is some sort of 'tracking circle' on the left hand side that slowly goes round until it's full - but it doesn't give you a *number* (e.g. 4/10). If I remember correctly, the number is shown briefly when moving upwards in the challenge.

[image: in-game]

More importantly, after a round's finished you can't find this information either. (It says 'kill 10 Scouts...' but not how many you've killed so far.)

[image: After a round]

Heck, you can't even see the progress in your Soldier menu!

[image: player stats]

Am I missing something to show the current progress of the challenge? A keyboard shortcut? Clicking on a specific item? Sacrificing a goat to the Earthmother? I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: When you spawn in the map, it tends to show your progress for a split second off to the left. If you're on a segment that is something like "get 5 kills in one life with single-shot rifles", it will update live as you get those 5 kills. Otherwise, I'm with you, I'd like a better tracker.

Comment: Make it in a answer Kaizerwolf, this is exactly what he is looking for(I came to answer that). Battlefield 1 lacks some of the good features for medal like we had with BF4. Heck, they should improve a lot what they ask for medals to not main the team (aka 5 HS with a revolver)

Answer (score 0):

This is a glitch. At least it is for me on XB1.

The progress shows when I move out and then back in to the medals page a few times, or at least twice.

Also you don't have to wait for the end of game screen to check medal progress or even change your tracked medal. If you press  <kbd>ESC</kbd> during a match, it brings up the menu options and to the right of it your current tracked medal.

Click on the medal and it will show you your current progress on the medal screen, and allow you to change your tracked medal. If the progress doesn't show, navigate back out and then in again to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The tracked medal number is displayed inside the circle every time you respawn;
the number has been also added to the medal page, and is displayed between parenthesis after the task description.

Example:

> [ ] Get kills as Medic (10/100)